# Where does Apache Foundation keep checksums for projects?

Tags: apache, checksum

Most tools I download have a SHASUM or MD5 file listed somewhere to checksum files once download.

However, I downloaded Zookeeper recently and was having a heck of a time finding the checksums for it. I could create them myself, but would also like to verify against a public checksum.

Might they also sign releases? How would I go about verifying with GPG.

Comment: I honestly can't understand what you're asking. Is this a technical question related to Apache HTTP Server, a general question about release policies followed by the Apache Foundation or a doubt about some software package you want to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Apache Foundation does not maintain a centralized checksum repository for binary distributions for any Apache project, nor do they mandate it.  Same goes for a signing certificate.  Both of these are project-level concerns and must be requested per-project through their project-specific issue tracker.